# Installing Laravel on MAMP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, mamp

I downloaded the [latest version of Laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) from Github, unzipped it, and then placed it inside of the htdocs folder in MAMP. MAMP is running PHP version 5.4.10 and therefore fulfills Laravel's requirement of PHP >= 5.3.7. I tried using the terminal to install composer by entering:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

And was greeted with an error reading:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env php
 Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
 Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

 The detect_unicode setting must be disabled.
 Add the following to the end of your `php.ini`:
 detect_unicode = Off

 A php.ini file does not exist. You will have to create one.
 If you can not modify the ini file, you can also run `php -d option=value` to modify ini     values on the fly. You can use -d multiple times.
```

When I try to load

```
http://localhost:8888/laravel/public/
```

in my browser, the PHP error log shows

```
05-Sep-2013 16:57:03 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

I have a feeling that this error has a fairly simple solution, but as I'm very new to Laravel I need to be pointed in the right direction in regards to solving this.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try: _Add the following to the end of your 'php.ini':  detect_unicode = Off_?

Comment: For your own sanity, please consider using Vagrant or another virtual machine provider so that you don't have to deal with Mac's non-standard install of apache/php etc. Just a suggestion tho, use what works for you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to get Composer up and running before you can install Laravel 4. That step failed here.

Try running this command instead:

```
$ curl -sS getcomposer.org/installer | php -d detect_unicode=Off
```

It will circumvent the problem so you can get on with installing Laravel 4.

EDIT:

For a global installation of Composer, do this afterwards:

```
$ sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer.phar
$ alias composer='/usr/local/bin/composer.phar'
```

Then, in your directory where you would like to put Laravel 4 into,

```
$ php composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
```

Comment: Do I need to install this while in a certain directory in the terminal?

Comment: nope, Composer can go anywhere you like. On my Linux system, I chose to put it into `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: This worked just fine. But, I can't seem to find the composer.phar file.

Comment: Your answer worked when I downloaded composer while in the applications directory. But, when in usr/local/bin it gives me

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env php
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...
Could not create file /usr/local/bin/composer.phar: fopen(/usr/local/bin/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
Download failed: fopen(/usr/local/bin/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: Well, I'm 100% that I have composer installed now. But, http://localhost:8888/laravel/public/ still doesn't work

Comment: Well, you have to install Laravel too. After installing, it's best to point your Apache vhost to the newly created `laravel/public` folder.

Comment: It's still throwing me the same error in the error log. Composer is installed but nothing has changed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36881/discussion-between-lance-and-cuewizchris)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, your system is not using `MAMP`'s `PHP` but instead uses the `php` that comes with your mac.

I made notes on how I installed `laravel` when `MAMP` is already installed. I hope you and others find it helpful.

**a.** add `MAMP`'s `PHP` to `PATH VARIABLE` in `.bash_profile`

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin:$PATH
```

**b.** install `Composer`
-go to http://www.getcomposer.org/ ->getting started ->globally copy and execute the following commands at the terminal…

```
cd ~
curl -sS https:/?getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

**c.** install `Laravel` in `MAMP/htdocs` folder using `composer`,
at the terminal…

```
cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
composer create-project laravel/laravel neji --prefer-dist
```

******where neji is the name of your website/project

**d.** edit  `/private/etc/hosts`

```
sudo nano /private/etc/hosts
```

add `127.0.0.1 neji` at the buttom of the file. save and exit

**e.** using any textEditor edit `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf`
uncomment by removing the `#` before include… on the virtual hosts, see below where...

```
 # Virtual Hosts
 #Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

becomes...

```
 # Virtual Hosts
 Include  /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

**f.** using any textEditor edit `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`
add the following text at the bottom

```
# I am not sure about this since DocumentRoot does not points to the public folder
# but I still added it and it's working, maybe someone will clarify this part
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias www.localhost
#     ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
#     CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

# this one, I think is the code that makes it work bec the DocumentRoot points to public folder
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin neji.dev
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/neji/public/"
    ServerName neji.dev
    ServerAlias www.neji
#     ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
#     CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

** **2 things to note**

1st, set ServerName to your projectName(neji.dev)

2nd, set DocumentRoot to the public folder

**g.** open your project using your fav browser

```
neji.dev/
```

******don’t forget the `/` at the end

You should see the `laravel` welcome page.

Then after a few days switch to `VM` :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're missing the dependencies.

The installation [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/installation) is pretty clear:

> Once Composer is installed, download the latest version of the Laravel framework and extract its contents into a directory on your server. Next, in the root of your Laravel application, run the `php composer.phar install` (or composer install) command to install all of the framework's dependencies. This process requires Git to be installed on the server to successfully complete the installation.

You've already downloaded and and unzipped the Laravel files into your `htdocs` folder, so now just run:

```
php composer.phar install
```

in your terminal to install the dependencies.

That should fix the issue.

And when you want to update Laravel, just run:

```
php composer.phar update
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you "install" MAMP, the php command in terminal not use the PHP of MAMP but the default mac os one

Just type in terminal :
which php
it return :
/usr/bin/php

For install Laravel without extra params, just update your .bash_profile file to use the PHP of MAMP

I wrote a doc (in french) here :

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1eXaL8mAv7bGQ_xq_f6sO5jf23X7APuRwCDAexHN52mY/edit

regards

Answer (score 0):

In addition to determining which version of php you're using:
`which php`
and editing the path in .bash_profile (as others have already explained very well), be sure to check if php still exists in /usr/bin
`ls /usr/bin/php`
and if so, then disable it by renaming it to something like php.bak
`cd /usr/bin`
`sudo mv php php.bak`
In my case I had done all the resetting of the path variable in .bash_profile plus checking the permissions plus following up on a bunch of debates about other ways of configuring the path variable etc, but after all that my problems were solved by disabling the old php in /usr/bin altogether.